# LINQ to SQL assign results to another object in VB.net?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, linq

I am trying to assign results of `vw_Source_Columns` to `vw_UI_List_Search_Columns` in select statement. How to do in vb.net?

```
Partial Public Class vw_Source_Columns
    Public Property Source As String
    Public Property Field_Name As String
    Public Property Field_Type As String
    Public Property strSourceColumn As String
    Public Property strSourceName As String
    Public Property strDataViewName As String
    Public Property intColumnID As Integer
    Public Property intMaster As Integer

End Class

Public Class vw_UI_List_Search_Columns
    Public Property Source As String
    Public Property Field_Name As String
    Public Property Field_Type As String
    Public Property strSourceColumn As String
    Public Property strSourceName As String
End Class


Dim query = From tblSources In writingEntities.vw_Source_Columns.AsNoTracking
            query = query.Where(Function(tblSources) tblSources.strSourceName = tblName).OrderBy(Function(tblSources) tblSources.strSourceColumn)
            'Dim lstfields As List(Of vw_UI_List_Source_Columns) = query.ToList() 
               '' assign query results of List (Of vw_UI_List_Source_Columns) 
               '' to List (Of vw_UI_List_Search_Columns) to suitable columns.
```

How to do this in vb.net? I use to do in c# by using `new` keyword in select.

Comment: Use "New With" as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528610/what-does-the-new-with-syntax-do-in-vb-linq

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim lstfields As List(Of vw_UI_List_Search_Columns) = query.Select(Function(e) New vw_UI_List_Search_Columns With {.Source = e.Source, .Field_Name = e.Field_Name, etc...}).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

you must create an instance and set manually the properties like this:

```
Dim lstfields As List(Of vw_UI_List_Search_Columns)
lstfields = query.Select(Function(SourceItem) _
                             New vw_UI_List_Search_Columns() with _
                                 {.Source = SourceItem.Source,
                                  .Field_Name = SourceItem.Field_Name,
                                  .Field_Type = SourceItem.Field_Type,
                                  .strSourceColumn = SourceItem.strSourceColumn,
                                  .strSourceName = SourceItem.strSourceName}).ToList()
```

If you were using inheritance, then class `vw_Source_Columns` was heiress from `vw_UI_List_Search_Columns`, You could do exactly the way you did (just in addition `Cast(Of vw_UI_List_Search_Columns)` like this:

```
Public Class vw_Source_Columns 
    Inherits  vw_UI_List_Search_Columns

    Public Property strDataViewName As String
    Public Property intColumnID As Integer
    Public Property intMaster As Integer
End Class

Public Class vw_UI_List_Search_Columns
    Public Property Source As String
    Public Property Field_Name As String
    Public Property Field_Type As String
    Public Property strSourceColumn As String
    Public Property strSourceName As String
End Class


Dim query = From tblSources In writingEntities.vw_Source_Columns.AsNoTracking
query = query.Where(Function(tblSources) tblSources.strSourceName = tblName).OrderBy(Function(tblSources) tblSources.strSourceColumn)
Dim lstfields As List(Of vw_UI_List_Source_Columns) = query.Cast(Of vw_UI_List_Search_Columns).ToList()
```