# Vb to c# conversion of a linq query that contains a with statement

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

So I've been working on this project to convert code from vb.net to c#.net, but I've never worked with vb. The code has many Linq statements, some of which contain a 'with' statement, which I know is local only to vb. I've done research and found how to convert a regular with statement to c# but not how to include that kind of stuff into a linq query. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the statement that I'm trying to convert

```
Dim query = (From k In dt Select New ProductDecode With {
    .CompanyCode = k.Field(Of Decimal)("CompanyCode"),
    .ProductType = k.Field(Of String)("ProductType"),
    .Product = k.Field(Of String)("Product"),
    .ProductDescription = k.Field(Of String)("ProductDescription")}).ToList()`
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528610/what-does-the-new-with-syntax-do-in-vb-linq may be of interest .

Answer (score 1):

So you want to convert a `DataTable` to a `List<ProductDecode>`:

```
var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            select new ProductDecode
            {
                CompanyCode = row.Field<decimal>("ProductType"),
                ProductType = row.Field<string>("ProductType"),
                Product = row.Field<string>("Product"),
                ProductDescription = row.Field<string>("ProductDescription"),
            };
var list = query.ToList();
```

or only with method syntax (nicer in C# than in VB.NET):

```
var list = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new ProductDecode
    {
        CompanyCode = row.Field<decimal>("ProductType"),
        ProductType = row.Field<string>("ProductType"),
        Product = row.Field<string>("Product"),
        ProductDescription = row.Field<string>("ProductDescription"),
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

As mjwills already pointed out in his link, the `With` suggests an anonymous type instead of an existing one. In C#, I think you know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The VB.Net `New ClassName With { .Field = Value, ... }` construct is field initialisation during construction. In C# it's `new ClassName { Field = Value, ... }`. So your code may be conveted as follows:

```
var query = (from k in dt select new ProductDecode {
    CompanyCode = k.Field<decimal>("CompanyCode"),
    ProductType = k.Field<string>("ProductType"),
    Product = k.Field<string>("Product"),
    ProductDescription = k.Field<string>("ProductDescription")
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks that took a lot of the errors I previously had away, but now I get invalid expression term error for the decimal and strings. I even tried using them as a cast type but that didn't work either

Comment: Oh, `Field<T>()` is an extension method so I should have used parentheses instead of brackets. Please see the updated answer.